# Hashchange event listener listens before event handler is attached to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

I have the following code

```
console.info('checking if url contains hash');
if (!location.hash) {
  console.warn('if-block replacing hash to empty!');
  location.href = '#';

  // Running route() to trigger Router.otherwise()
  console.info('running route() from if-block(hash doesn\'t exist)');
  route(location.hash.slice(1));
} else {
  // URL contains a hash. Running Router.when() to load template
  console.info('running route() from else-block(hash already present in url)');
  route(location.hash.slice(1));
}

// Bind hashchange-event to window-object... duh
console.info('binding hashchange event');
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
  console.info('running route() from hashchange');
  route(location.hash.slice(1));
});
```

Clearly, the event listener is attached after the else-if block. My console's output verifies this

```
2015-02-13 12:51:14.281 main.js:69 checking if url contains hash
2015-02-13 12:51:14.284 main.js:71 if-block replacing hash to empty!
2015-02-13 12:51:14.290 main.js:75 running route() from if-block(hash doesn\'t exist)
2015-02-13 12:51:16.677 main.js:84 binding hashchange event
2015-02-13 12:51:16.678 main.js:86 running route() from hashchange
```

It looks like the event listener somehow picks up the previously triggered hashchange event.
This only occurs when the url is `example.com`, not `example.com/#`. If `/` or `/#` is missing from the url when you enter the site this phenomenon triggers.

Edit: The problem I'm experiencing is that the `hashchange` event listener is triggering before it's even listening to hash changes. I'm wondering if that's normal.

Another edit:
An even clearer example showing that when I first run `getEventListeners(window)`, no listeners are attached to the `hashchange` event. Despite that, when I do add the event listener, it picks up a previously triggered `hashchange`
[image: console logs]

Am I missing something here or what's going on?
Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Bypass what? Nothing in what is shown indicates event firing prematurely. Please explain issue in more detail. Not at all clear what is expected

Comment: @charlietfl I added clarification to my OP

Comment: what makes you say it triggers prematurely? Your edit is a statement that isn't supported by what is shown in console logs A demo that replicates issue would help

Comment: @charlietfl the console logs states that on line 69, my if-else block starts running and a hash is added to the url, therefore triggering an `hashchange` event. But I haven't attached an event listener to `hashchange` yet, seen at line 84 in the console logs.

Comment: then you need to show more code, the way code is shown the logs are right

Comment: @charlietfl how is it right? I haven't attached an event listener to `hashchange` when I do change the hash. Yet, when I add the listener it triggers right away since I did change the hash *before* it was added. Could you explain it in a reply? I'll see if I can reproduce the issue in a fiddle

Comment: some of your logs have nothing to do with event

Comment: @charlietfl added an image with more logs. Could you please help out if you know what's going in instead of just saying nothing's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify your code to

```js
location.hash = 'foobar';
window.onhashchange = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = 'You should not see me. But you do :(';
};
```

To fix the problem, you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) to delay the addition of the event handler:

```js
location.hash = 'foobar';
setTimeout(function(){ // Delayed code
  window.onhashchange = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'You should not see me. And you do not :)';
  };
}, 0);
```

Comment: I understand I can use that as a work around. But why is the issue occurring in the first place?

Comment: @rymdsylt Not sure, maybe it is updated asynchronously. You can see the `hash` setter steps in the [URL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#dom-urlutils-hash), but I don't know enough that spec to see where it happens.

Comment: Well, since your example helped me solve it, I'm marking this as solved. Thanks dude!